# summation using List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, z3py

I am trying to perform a sum as following:

```
list=[b_{i}{j}=SUMMATION(|d_{i}{j}| - |g_{j}{k}|)] or simply

list=[SUMMATION(|d_{i}{j}| - |g_{j}{k}|)]
```

for this using list comprehension I am trying following:

```
d=Function ('d', IntSort(), IntSort(),RealSort())
g=Function ('g', IntSort(), IntSort(),RealSort())
b=Function ('b', IntSort(),RealSort())

drug=[d(i,j)==randint(1,5) for i in range (input) for j in range (input)]
gene=[g(i,j)==randint(1,5) for i in range (input) for j in range (input)]
benefit=[[[(b(i) == b(i) + abs(d(i)(j)) - abs(g(j)(k))) for k in range(j) ] for j in range(i) ] for i in range(input) ]
```

but I am getting following error I think my list comprehension is wrong as I am getting following error, any suggestion?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
benifit=[ [[(b(i)== b(i)+abs(d(i,j)) - abs(g(j)(k)))   for k in  range(j)]  for j in  range(i)]  for i in range(input) ]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any help?

Comment: for k in j and for j in i, both j and i are integer, you are trying to iterate int object

Answer (score 1):

I'm not currently convinced your code is doing what you think it's doing. However, I'm not familiar with z3py, so I could be mistaken here.

First, take a look at this snippet.

```
d=Function ('d', IntSort(), IntSort(),RealSort())
```

I assume `Function` is a callable defined by z3py which produces another callable.

```
d(i,j)==randint(1,5)
```

In this snippet, you're calling your function d with two arguments, then you're comparing it to a random number. It seems like you might think you're assigning the value to a square matrix called d; perhaps I'm wrong. Either way, unless calling d somehow modifies state, you may as well have a 1 in 5 chance of being true, otherwise false. (alternately, if you expect calling d to produce values outside of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, the distribution would be different).

Regardless, that line populates the variable `data` with a list of booleans whose length is the square of the value of `input`.

```
d[i][j]
```

This snippet is what makes me think the above. It's the classic way to index into a list of lists.

```
b(i) == b(i) + abs(d[i][j]) - abs(g[j][k])
```

This is very suspicious to me. Unless you somehow overrode the equality operator, this also produces a boolean value. Further, unless calling the function `b` modifies state or otherwise returns different results for the same arguments, it's strictly equivalent to `bool(abs(d[i][j]) - abs(g[j][k]))`. This was the kicker that makes me think **you may be confusing equivalence checking with assignment**. The result is `benefit` will also be a flat list of booleans.

As a final note, I think good style would dictate that you turn your last comprehension inside out to simplify it.

```
benefit=[[[(b(i) == b(i) + abs(d[i][j]) - abs(g[j][k])) for k in range(j) ] for j in range(i) ] for i in range(input) ]
```

should instead read

```
benefit=[(b(i) == b(i) + abs(d[i][j]) - abs(g[j][k])) for i in range(input) for j in range(i) for k in range(j)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
benefit=[[[(b(i) == b(i) + abs(d[i][j]) - abs(g[j][k])) for k in range(j) ] for j in range(i) ] for i in range(input) ]
```

You cannot iterate over an integer variable, i.e. running `f(k) for k in j` where j is an int is invalid. You must create an iterable object to iterate over `f(k) for k in range(j)`

Comment: I am actually using the same way I pasted the old list mistakenly. But it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do with a comprehension can also be done (using a few more lines) with nested loops. I can't tell quite what you're trying to accomplish, and also have a slight suspicion that what you actually want to do isn't best done with list comprehensions.

Can you re-write your `benefit = ...` line just using loops? It'll make clearer to us what you want to do, and it might just be the right thing do anyways.